# Control HTML element by using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do something really practical.

```
<table class="annplain" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" width="325">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td><p><strong><a href="#Title" class="Title">Title</a></strong><br />
                <span class="annfrom">date<br />
                </span>
                    <span class="content">.</span>
        <br />
                <br />
            </p></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

Title
Information – 05/11/2009 at 15:30
```

I got many of such kind HTML table generating from my PHP code. What I have to is to Hide all the content in section first, the people only can see the title. And then when people click on the title , i want to display the span tag content.

I used toggle function with jQuery to work as switch for Span content. My question is how can I do it for all the table instead of hard code like

```
  $(".title").click(function () {
                $(".content").toggle();

            });

$(".title1").click(function () { $(".content2").toggle();

            });
```

For all my table.

Thanks, I am looking forward to your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do not use a div for the title and a div for the table (without title).

Hide/show the div which contains th table when you click the header.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Since every content to be toggled is always share the same table cell with the title that initiate the toggle. So you can use that to make it general.

So you html should be like this:
`<table class="annplain" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" width="325">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td><p><strong><a href="#Title1" class="title">Title 1</a></strong><br />
                    <span class="annfrom">date<br />
                    </span>
                        <span class="content"> Content 1 </span>
<br />
                    <br />
                </p></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><p><strong><a href="#Title2" class="title">Title 2</a></strong><br />
                    <span class="annfrom">date<br />
                    </span>
                        <span class="content"> Content 2 </span>
<br />
                    <br />
                </p></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>`

And your jQuery code should looks like this:

```
$(".title").click(function () {
    var aParentTD = $(this).closest("td");
    var aContent  = aParentTD.find(".content");  // Content in the same TD with Title
    aContent.toggle();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You need to add a check for null results, though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use a class of Title for all of your tables then you can do this:

```
$(".Title").click(function () {
  $(".content",$(this).closest("td")).toggle();
});
```

$(this).closest("td") will get you to the td and thus limit the scope of the content selection to that which is under the title that was clicked.